# Looking for a passwordless authentication system

Tags: open-source, web-development, security, authentication

I'm looking for an authentication system that works like this: You type in your e-mail address, you get an e-mail with a link that signs you in and keeps you signed in on that device until you explicitly log out.

The closest thing I find to this is auth0 passwordless. But this isn't perfect because you still need to enter a code, rather then automatically getting logged in, and it relies on a third party. I'd like an open source tool, that doesn't rely on any third party.

Comment: Firebase offers this (This sentence is just to complete the 30 characters)

Answer (score 1):

Auth0 does this without entering a code. Their [docs](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless/guides/email-magic-link) even say:

`This link will allow them to login directly when clicking on it. It is similar in function to them getting an email with a one-time-use code in it, returning to your app, and entering the code, **but without having to actually perform those steps**.`

If you want to run this service yourself, not a third party, then [look for repos on GitHub](https://www.google.com/search?q=magic+link+login+github) or a similar website.